# Typescript Generic Constraint When Extending An Interface - '?' expected

Tags: typescript

I'm looking at generics and from the typescript docs I can see that we can pass the type when calling the generic function or leave the type to type inference.

However, if the type expected is an extended interface then specifying the extension 'Names extends Middle' throws a '? expected' error.

Is passing the extension correct and what is this '? expected'

```
export interface Names {
    firstname: string
    lastname: string
}

export interface Middle {
    middlename: string
}

const names = {
    firstname: "Peter",
    lastname: "parker",
    middlename: "spidey"
}

function test<T extends Middle>(details: T) {
    return details.middlename
}

// Throws error ? expected
test<Names extends Middle>(names))
```

When left to type Inference it works

```
test(names))
```

Comment: names is created without a type therefore it is any type. You are telling the function that you are passing a Names type

Comment: When calling function using `extends` is invalid syntax in generic type position, hence the error

Comment: Specifying type explicitly is useless in this case, but if you're trying to say that you're passing something that is both `Names` and `Middle` you can go with `test<Names & Middle>(names)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De-facto `names` is of type `Names & Middle`, `Names` does not extend `Middle`, so this makes no sense here (and would not be valid even if that were the case). The only thing relevant to this invocation is that the interface `Middle` is satisfied, so this will work just fine:

```
test<Middle>(names)
```

In the current form of `test` there is no reason to be any more specific because `T` is not really used in any meaningful way, but you could also invoke it via:

```
test<Names & Middle>(names)
```

---

Example where the generic would matter:

```
function log<T extends Middle>(details: T) {
    console.log(details.middlename); // uses the Middle type

    return details; // Returns a more specific type than just Middle
}

const person = {
    middlename: 'steve',
    greet() {
        alert('hello ' +  this.middlename);
    }
}

log(person).greet(); // `greet` would not be recognized here without the generic
```